# How to GET a single record from collection of data on routed request with params?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a simple node server that on a GET request for the following paths, returns some static JSON:

`/employees
/employees/:id`

I've created 2 GET requests, but my problem comes when trying to GET 1 employee as the employees data doesn't exist, I've tried using a variable to store the data in /employees but this doesn't seem to work. Do I need to combine and check if an id exists?

```
 let employees = []
```

app.get('/employees', (req, res) => {
        let data = generate(100)
        employees = data

```
    console.log(req.body)

    res.json({
        "status": "success",
        "data": data,
        "message": []
    }).end()
})

app.get('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {
    let employee = _.find(employees, {"id": req.params.id}) //employees doesn't exist

    res.json({
        "status": "success",
        "data": employee,
        "message": []
    }).end()
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just return an 400 error, if you don't have an employee with given ID?

Comment: My problem is that when I request on /employees/:id the employees data doesn't exist if the id is correct or not

Comment: That's correct. There're two different callbacks, so employees only created in a first one.  Do you need some mock data? Why don't you create some simple database and make a request to it?

Comment: Or, just create an object outside of app.get. Just in a top of the module

Comment: For now all I need is mock data with no DB, the generate function in /employees is creating my mock dataset. So can I combine the two requests, make sure the data has been generated, and then check for params to either return all data or 1 record?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock your data in this way

```
/*import's block*/

const employees = [...your data...]

app.get('/employees', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)

    res.json({
        "status": "success",
        "data": data,
        "message": []
    }).end()
})

app.get('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {
    let employee = _.find(employees, {"id": req.params.id})

    res.json({
        "status": "success",
        "data": employee,
        "message": []
    }).end()
})
```

I'd add some check if data exist and return error 400 if not

Comment: What if I only want to make employees data available if a request is made on the employees route?

Comment: You can just set let employees = [] and fill this variable only after /employees call

Comment: That’s what I’m doing in my example though with no success, employees is empty on the employees/:id request

Comment: That's because you declare employees variable inside of /employees callback.

Comment: /employees/:id callback in your case just don't 'see' that variable

Comment: I declare the employees variable outside of the requests, I only set the employees inside /employees?

Comment: Is there anywhere I can demo this? Any node fiddles?